# Fastest-Cleanest way to update database (mysql large tables)

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a website feeded with large mysql tables (>50k of rows in some tables). Lets name one table "MotherTable". Every night I update the site with a new csv file (produced locally) that has to substitute "MotherTable" data.

The way I do this currently (I am not an expert, as you see), is:
- First, I TRUNCATE the MotherTable table. 
- Second, I import the csv file to the empty table, with columns separated by "/" and skipping 1 line.

As the csv file is not very small, there are some seconds (or even a minute) when the MotherTable is empty, so the web users that make SELECTS on this table find nothing.

Obviously, I don't like that. Is there any procedure to update MotherTable in a way users note nothing? If not, what would be the quickest way to update the table with the new csv file?

Thank you!

Comment: If I were doing it programatically I would create a temp table, populate it, then delete the original and rename the temp table.

Comment: Mmm, yes, I am going to do it in php. May you help me with the code?

Comment: No - you write the code and when you have problems come back here and post a question.

Comment: Savage[.](http://www.google.com)

Comment: LOL @PhiterFernandes

Comment: Ok, I'll do it. Thanks @JayBlanchard